# prevent expect from exiting on EOF

Tags: bash, fork, expect

I have an expect script that connects to a vpn using openconnect. The script works perfectly, except that I don't know how to keep openconnect alive once the password has been provided and expect has reached the EOF. I think I need to fork the process, but I need it to keep the password somehow. Here is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./openconnect
expect "sudo"
send "sudo_password\r"
expect "password:"
send "vpn_password\r"
expect /Connected\stun1\sas/ #expect connected tun1 as some ip
```

and openconnect

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo -k
sudo -S openconnect --juniper --user username --csd-wrapper ~/juniper-vpn-py/tnc vpn_server
```

The output gets to connected tun1 as some ip as expected, but then expect closes and so does the process is spawned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wait for the spawned process to finish before exiting the Expect script or the spawned process may be killed prematurely. Try like this:

```
expect "Connected tun1 as"
expect -timeout -1 eof     ; # change the timeout value as needed
```

or

```
expect "Connected tun1 as"
interact
```

Comment: "interact" worked. "expect eof" didn't work with openconnect - it appears to get EOF after about 10 seconds, maybe openconnect closes stdin when launched from expect?

Comment: sounds like it timed out waiting for the EOF. try `expect -timeout -1 eof`

Comment: will the `openconnect` command keep running in foreground? or it'll exit soon and have its child process running in background?

Comment: `openconnect` runs in foreground by default. It can be run in the background with `-b` but that leads to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578588/tcl-expect-kills-child-of-child-process) where the child process appears to be killed by SIGHUP even though `-ignore HUP` is used.